# MySQL Family Tree

Tags: mysql, syntax, foreign-keys, family-tree

[Errors Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJTTf.png)

Any idea on these syntax errors? Related to FOREIGN KEY syntax? No idea! I removed the ENGINE=INNODB; lines but it still isn't working.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Marriage;
CREATE TABLE Marriage (
    marriageID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(marriageID),
    date DATE,
    place varchar(100)
);
```

That top one works fine--the real trouble begins with the next one's FOREIGN KEYS:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MarriagePerson;
CREATE TABLE MarriagePerson (
    marriagePersonID int NOT NULL,
    marriageID int,
    personID int,
    PRIMARY KEY(marriagePersonID),  
    FOREIGN KEY marriageID REFERENCES Marriage(marriageID),
    FOREIGN KEY personID REFERENCES Person(personID)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Person;
CREATE TABLE Person (
     personID int NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(personID),
     firstName varchar(100),
     lastName varchar(100),
     gender  ENUM(male, female, nonBinary),
     birthDate DATE,
     birthPlace varchar(100),
     deathDate DATE,
     deathPlace varchar(100),
     causeOfDeath varchar(100),
     note varchar(1000)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Parent;
CREATE TABLE Parent (
    parentID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(parentID),
    FOREIGN KEY personID int,
    FOREIGN KEY parentPersonID int,
    relationship ENUM(sperm, egg)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: You have some foreign keys in the `Parent` table, but they don't reference anything.

Comment: And what are those syntax errors?

Comment: Can you post the errors?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running it in the same order as you have posted,

In the second query you have:

```
FOREIGN KEY personID REFERENCES Person(personID)
```

Which is not created yet. The Person table is created in the next query.